# Approximately calculate the probability that the average lifetime of all the bulbs in a particular box exceeds $2500$ hours.

Tags: probability, expectation, central-limit-theorem, variance

I'm trying to solve the following questions

> Suppose that the lifetimes of light bulbs are independent, exponentially distributed random variables with a mean of $2000$ hours each.
>   1) Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen light bulb survives for more than $2500$ hours.

For this I got $e^{-2500/2000}$ (I don't know if this is needed for the other parts but thought I'd mention it).

I'm stuck on the other two parts

> Suppose that the bulbs come in boxes of $100$.
>   2) Approximately calculate the probability that the average lifetime of all the bulbs in a particular box exceeds $2500$ hours.
>   3) Approximately calculate the probability that the sum of the lifetimes of all the bulbs in a particular box exceeds $220,000$ hours.

I know I need to use the central limit theorem somehow for both so I need to calculate the mean and variance for both parts. For number 2, I have no clue what to do. For number 3, I calculated:
$\text{mean} = 2000\times100=200000$
$\text{variance} = 2000\times100^2=20000000$
Then I did 
$$P\left(z>\frac{220000-\text{mean}}{\text{sq. root of variance}}\right) = p(z>4.47)$$
but since you can't find probabilities for values greater than $3$ in the $z$ table, I got stuck and assumed I did it wrong.

So I really don't know how to solve either. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I think the variance is 2000^2x100 instead of 2000x(100^2).

Comment: When you sum *identical* variables, the variance is multiplied by $n^2$. When you sum independent but identically distributed variables, the variance is only multiplied by $n$ (because the covariances are all zero).

Comment: You might have gotten a downvote because you did not use proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For future reference, continue to post your thoughts and attempts, and try to use proper spelling to the best of your abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
I call the life time of a particular bulb $X_i$

1) Is fine.

2) There are 100 bulbs in the box, and hence the average is
$$\bar X = \frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}}{100}.$$

Then
$$E[\bar X]  =\frac{1}{100}E[X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}] = \frac{1}{100}\cdot100E[X_1] = 2000$$
and
\begin{align*}
\Var(\bar X) &= \Var\left(\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}
}{100}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{100^2}\left[\Var(X_1)+\dotsb+\Var(X_{100})\right]\\
&= \frac{2000^2}{100}\\
&= 40000.
\end{align*}
Then the problem becomes
\begin{align*}
P\left(\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}}{100}>2500\right)&=1-P\left(\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}}{100}\leq 2500\right)\\
&\approx1-P\left(Z\leq\frac{2500-2000}{\sqrt{40000}}\right)\tag 1\\\
&=1-\Phi(2.5)\tag 2\\
&=0.006209665
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ $Z$ is a standard normal and we are using a normal approximation, and in $(2)$, $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

3) Let $S = X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}$. Then
$$E[S] = E[X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}] =100\cdot 2000 = 200000$$
and
$$\Var(S) = \Var(X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}) = 100\cdot 2000^2 =20000^2.$$

Then the problem becomes
\begin{align*}
P(S>220000)&=1-P(S\leq 220000)\\
&\approx 1-P\left(Z\leq \frac{220000-200000}{\sqrt{20000^2}}\right)\\
&=1-\Phi(1)\\
&=0.1586553
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks :) your answers are correct! can u just explain how you knew to calculate the variance that way for both?

Comment: i just figured it out for 2) but i'm still confused for 3).

Comment: You are asked for the chance that a simple sum exceeds $220000$. So, you don't divide by anything since it is not an average, and so $\Var(X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}) = \text{Var}(X_1)+\dotsb+\text{Var}(X_{100}) = 100\text{Var}(X_1) = 100\cdot 2000^2$ where the first equality is true by independence and the second is true since they are identically distributed.

Comment: Also, if you found this answer satisfactory, consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: but wouldnt 100Var(X) = (100^2)xVar(x)? I thought u squared the constant...

Comment: Really? You are telling me that $$100\Var(X) = 100^2\Var(X)?$$ Be careful, you stop thinking. That does make any sense. You're thinking of $\Var(aX) = a^2\Var(X)$.

Comment: doesn't* make sense. Anyway, be careful. Good luck!